# Can't download anything on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, downloads

For months now I'm not able to download anything properly. Doesn't matter which browser I'm using. Even Ubuntu updates. Everything starts fine, but within 2 or 3 minutes the download speed drops to zero and does not go back. On chrome I get `"unknown network error"`. It's not the connection because other computers are working fine. I've been only able to download small files, like 10 mb or so. I've tried to install a new wifi driver, but nothing appear on the "aditional drivers" GUI.